# Managed c++ Unresolved token on calling a function

Tags: visual-studio-2010, managed-c++

I have a managed c++ project, and I added to it an header file (EDIT: Not of a class) which contains declarations of functions. The implementations are in a cpp file with the same name.

When I build the project I gets errors of "Unresolved token" "Unresolved external symbol".
when I put the implementation in the header file - there are no errors.

How can I fix this problem?

(I work on visual studio 2010)

thanks

Comment: The concept of adding a managed project to a header file is way too murky.  Post a snippet.